# NPM install causes a significant amount of errors in React Native

Tags: react-native, npm

This is most likely an issue with npm.

I have a react-native project that worked fine until I ran npm install.

Once I did this, I started to receive a significant amount of errors.

To name a couple:

- I received this for multiple pods:
  `The iOS Simulator deployment targets is set to 7.0, but the range of supported deployment target version for this platform is 8.0 to 12.1`
- There were also multiple modules that had missing files.

I was able to revert to a previous version of my node_modules, without running npm install, and there were no issues.

However, when I run `npm install`, the issue persists.

Wondering if anyone else has experienced this and found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

i believe you may have conflicts with the version of npm you used previously. i am getting different results when using npm@5 and npm@6 to install.